# Boost nuget package for VS2015

Tags: c++, boost, visual-studio-2015

It fails with

> 1>\solutions\packages\boost_thread.1.58.0.0\lib\native\src\win32\thread.cpp(1007):
>   error C2491: 'boost::on_process_enter': definition of dllimport
>   function not allowed

Did I miss something or something went broken in boost (or nuget package) for VS2015?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous definition of BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK (in property sheet) interfered with the nuget package which (apparently) links statically

2020 update: just switch to `vcpkg`, really

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use precompiled packages instead of source packages. For example https://www.nuget.org/packages/boost_thread-vc140/1.59.0

Comment: it is definitely an option, my concern is rapid bugfix cycle of vs2015, can you ensure users that every time new update of VS is released you would provide precompiled packages built with latest update in timely manner?

Comment: BTW, Sergey, I've added an issue to boost package related to microsoft clang codegen, would you comment please.

Comment: I generate new packages for new Boost versions for the latest VS updates. Usually, when Microsoft releases a new VS Update there is a new Boost library. Sometimes, I [re]generate new NuGet packages on demand if there is a bug reason. About CLang in VS, I would like to see an official support from Boost.org first.

Comment: sounds good enough, will add a task to upgrade our projects with precompiled package.
oh, I see... I guess we will not see it for a long time, boost guys just dont want to mess with it, at least I got this impression...

Comment: Sergey, I see precompiled packages are not up to date with latest VS. 1.60 for update 1 when VS update 2 was already available, and the fresh 1.61 with update 2 and VS update 3 is out of the oven. Do we know for sure that ABI compatibility between updates 1-2-3 is preserved?

Comment: 2 kreuzerkrieg. This's what I've found about VC++ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B#ABI "The Visual C++ compiler ABI have historically changed between major compiler releases." I'm not aware of changes in ABI between VS updates.

Comment: yes, I know. the disturbing part is that in vcc blog when update released they always asked if ABI comp. is preserved, and they always answer that they working hard to preserve it. its somewhat different from,-"yes, it is definitely preserved" :) just askin, I personally have an impression that it is, but go figure